# Npgsql: wrong encoding

Tags: postgresql, encoding, diacritics, npgsql

I've imported data from a PostgreSQL with encoding UTF8 into a PostgreSQL with encoding SQL_ASCII. Using pgAdminIII, I can see the accents in the words, but when I use Npgsql, the text fields are returned with a '?' character in place of the accented characters. I've tryed to use UNICODE as the ENCODING connection string parameter , but this doesn't worked.

I found a weird thing. Any correction I do in my application using my WPF form works and the accents begin to be correctly shown after the update.

Does somebody know a solution for this problem?

Thanks,

Danilo da Silva

Comment: Any specific reason you're trying to import non-ASCII data into a PostgreSQL with encoding SQL_ASCII?

Comment: My site hosting only allows to create PostgreSQL database with this encoding.